# Unable to insert data into postgres table from a remote database connection

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, dblink

I am trying to insert data into a postgres table from a remote database table. I have written the following query for this purpose but I am getting following error.

```
'[Code: 0, SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "table"
  Position: 13  [Script position: 141 - 146]'
```

```
create table clintrial_EP_map.lead_sponsors (row_id SERIAL, lead_sponsors character varying)

insert into table clintrial_ep_map (lead_sponsors) 

 (  select 
        *
    from
        dblink('dbname=x user=x host=x password=x port = x', 
    '
    SELECT
        distinct bm_dimt_clinical_trial.lead_sponsor
        FROM
        dwh_prod.bm_dimt_clinical_trial

        where dataset_version_id = xx and lead_sponsor_class = ''xx''

    '              
    ) as ls (
        lead_sponsor character varying
    )
)   
;
```

Please see, the following query is giving me desired output.

```
select 
        *
    from
        dblink('dbname=x user=x host=x password=x port = x', 
    '
    SELECT
        distinct bm_dimt_clinical_trial.lead_sponsor
        FROM
        dwh_prod.bm_dimt_clinical_trial

        where dataset_version_id = xx and lead_sponsor_class = ''xx''

    '              
    ) as ls (
        lead_sponsor character varying
    )

    ;
```

I am not able to find a syntax error near 'table' in my insert query. Any suggestions here will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query has two issues.
First: Create table is not ending with ; i am hoping that is typo and Second: Your insert statement is referring to schema name instead of schema qualified table name. And also using keyword 'table' in insert statment which is not required. So your correct query will be

```
create table clintrial_EP_map.lead_sponsors (row_id SERIAL, lead_sponsors character varying);
```

and

```
insert into clintrial_EP_map.lead_sponsors (lead_sponsors) 

 (  select * from
        dblink('dbname=x user=x host=x password=x port = x', 
    'SELECT
        distinct bm_dimt_clinical_trial.lead_sponsor
        FROM
        dwh_prod.bm_dimt_clinical_trial

        where dataset_version_id = xx and lead_sponsor_class = ''xx''
    '              
    ) as ls (lead_sponsor character varying)
 );
```

Comment: Are you able to connect and insert data now rshar?